# Html won’t link to css

Tags: html, css

I was just beginning my CSS when I noticed that it was no longer showing up whenever I tried running the code.

```html
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“./css/style.css”/>
```

My CSS and HTML files are in the same folder too.

I had no issues with this earlier so I’m confused as to why it’s an issue now. I’m using visual studio code for this.

Comment: <link rel=stylesheet” href=“./css/style.css”/>

Comment: if the CSS file is in the same folder then use `css/style.css` as a file-relative path.

Comment: If you are css file in the same folder where html file is then simply use this <link rel=stylesheet” href=“./style.css”/>

Comment: Watch out for those curly quotes. They need to be straight quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there might be a typo in your  tag. Make sure to use regular double quotes (") instead of the fancy quotes (“”). Also, check the file path to ensure it's correct. If the issue persists, try restarting your browser or clearing the cache.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```